# MsgBox with multiple 'past due' items

Tags: excel, vba, date, msgbox

I am building an LOP (List of Open Points) in Excel 2016 for a manufacturing project. Each action item will have a 'target date' for completion. My intention is every time the document is opened, a macro will run that will scan the document and every item that is past due, comparing the 'target date' to today's date, will trigger a MsgBox popup that states "There are past due items in the following row(s): X, Y, and Z." I have ran into two issues that I'm trying to resolve:

1. The range of cells for the 'target date' column (J) will not yield a result. It will display the MsgBox if I enter a single cell. For example, if I only put the range as J4, and J4 is past due, the MsgBox will display as intended. But, if I set the range as "J4:J999" with multiple entries past due in the J column and run it, it does nothing, not even give me an error.
2. I cannot figure out how to integrate the date comparison code into a multiple-output MsgBox code. Maybe once the range issue is resolved, it will help.

Below is the code I'm using to identify the past due cells in the J column and yield the MsgBox:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim cl As Range
Set cl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPEN ITEMS").Range("J4:J999")
If IsDate(cl) Then
    If Now >= cl Then
        MsgBox "There are past due items in the following row(s):" & "" & cl.Address, vbExclamation, "ACTION REQUIRED"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a loop. Using `IsDate` on a multi-cell `Range` will always return `False`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply BigBen, I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

EDIT: As per BigBen's comment, added control if no rows met the condition. (Thnx @BigBen)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim evalRange As Range
    Dim evalCell As Range
    Dim resultRows As String

    Set evalRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPEN ITEMS").Range("J4:J999")
    For Each evalCell In evalRange
        If IsDate(evalCell) Then
            If Now >= evalCell Then
                resultRows = resultRows & evalCell.Row & ","
            End If
        End If
    Next evalCell

    If resultRows <> vbNullString Then
        ' Remove last comma
        resultRows = Left$(resultRows, Len(resultRows) - 1)

        MsgBox "There are past due items in the following row(s):" & resultRows, vbExclamation, "ACTION REQUIRED"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe add a check that `resultRows` is not a blank string after the loop, but otherwise a good approach. Presumably the `MsgBox` should only occur if there are in fact past due items.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a loop over an array (probably prefered) but let me show you a way without any iteration:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim lr As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPEN ITEMS")

    'Get last used row and create a range object
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("J4:J" & lr)

    'Get data into array
    arr = Filter(.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(IF(" & rng.Address & ">=NOW(),ROW(" & rng.Address & "),""|""))"), "|", False)

    'Use array in any message you like
    MsgBox "There are past due items in the following row(s): " & Join(arr, ",")

End With

End Sub
```

Allthough this bypasses the need for any iteration, it does however make use of an array formula which on large data does slow things down (a 1000 rows isn't that much though).

---

> ***Note***: Keep in mind that the max amount of characters in a Msgbox prompt is approximately 1024.

I just tried this code on about 1000 lines all past due data, and allthough it was still fast, about half of them won't show in the messagebox!